# calculate and compare Ballistocardiogram (BCG) with Photoplethysmogram (PPG)

Tags: matlab

I have a task from my boss on calculating Ballistocardiogram (BCG) with Photoplethysmogram (PPG) using MATLAB. I would like to know how it can be done. Any kind soul can guide me?

As for what I know about how the test will be like is that I will need to take the BCG data and compare it against the PPG (I know Matlab has comparing function). So, in short, the PPG will be like a benchmark.

Ideally for BCG and PPG should have the same amount of data, but let's say the BCG for example 12 data and PPG only have 10. How do we compare it? because at every point it should match and I can't be removing the 2 extra data as it would be manipulating and that defeats the purpose already.

BCG: Ballistocardiogram,
PPG: Photoplethysmogram

I hope you guys can show me some light

-I don't have enough reputation to upload pic-

https://skydrive.live.com/embed?cid=0525DA685954952E&resid=525DA685954952E%21405&authkey=AOrI6qD7kFWV4_g
Diagram 1: find the differences of the corresponding data. As you can see in this diagram 1B against 2B

---

https://skydrive.live.com/embed?cid=0525DA685954952E&resid=525DA685954952E%21406&authkey=ACIhYwrTqZaNnp8
Diagram 2: let's say BCG has 12 data and PPG only 10(hopefully this don't occur). In this diagram, should 1D correspond to 2C? or? and if we remove 1C this will be manipulating the data.

*if there are other suggestions please tell me also. I don't need to use Matlab to compare. As long as I can compare, anyway is ok*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17438822/matlab-calculate-and-compare-bcg-with-ppg

Comment: add on: if i have 10000 data for example, i plot a graph and i wanna see it narrow down to 1000 data every button i press.. in short i press [start], it will show me 1st 1000 data and when i press [next] it will show me the next 1000 data instead of displaying out the entire 10000 data on the graph itself.. im new please guide me